# What are some advanced and modern resources on exploit writing?

Tags: security, exploit

I've read and finished both [Reversing: Secrets of Reverse Engineering](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0764574817) and [Hacking: The Art of Exploitation](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1593271441).  They both were illuminating in their own way but I still feel like a lot of the techniques and information presented within them is outdated to some degree.

When the infamous Phrack Article, [Smashing the Stack for Fun and Profit](http://insecure.org/stf/smashstack.html), was written 1996 it was just before what I sort of consider the Computer Security "golden age".

Writing exploits in the years that followed was relatively easy.  Some basic knowledge in C and Assembly was all that was required to perform buffer overflows and execute some arbitrary shell code on a victims machine.

To put it lightly, things have gotten *a lot* more complicated.  Now security engineers have to contend with things like [Address Space Layout Randomization (ASLR)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_space_layout_randomization), [Data Execution Prevention (DEP)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_Execution_Prevention), [Stack Cookies](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buffer_overflow_protection), Heap Cookies, and much more.  The complexity of writing exploits went up at least an order of magnitude.

You can't event *run* most of the buffer overrun exploits in the tutorials you'll find today without compiling with a bunch of flags to turn off modern protections.

Now if you want to write an exploit you have to devise ways to turn off DEP, spray the heap with your shell-code hundreds of times and attempt to guess a random memory location near your shellcode.  Not to mention the pervasiveness of managed languages in use today that are much more secure when it comes to these vulnerabilities.

I'm looking to extend my security knowledge beyond writing toy-exploits for a decade old system.  I'm having trouble locating resources that help address the issues of writing exploits in the face of all the protections I outlined above.

What are the more advanced and prevalent papers, books or other resources devoted to contending with the challenges of writing exploits for modern systems?

Answer (score 7):

You mentioned 'Smashing the stack'. Research-wise this article was out-dated before it was even published. The late 80s Morris worm used it (to exploit fingerd IIRC). At the time it caused a huge stir because back then every server was written in optimistic C.

It took a few (10 or so) years, but gradually everyone became more conscious of security concerns related to public-facing servers.

The servers written in C were subjected to lots of security analysis and at the same time server-side processing branched out into other languages and runtimes.

Today things look a bit different. Servers are not considered a big target. These days it's clients that are the big fish. Hijack a client and the server will allow you to operate under that client's credentials.

The landscape has changed.

Personally I'm a sporadic fan of playing assembly games. I have no practical use for them, but if you want to get in on this I'd recommend checking out the Metasploit source and reading their mailing lists. They do a lot of crazy stuff and it's all out there in the open.

Comment: +1 if only just for the 'metasploit' reference. That tool is gold in the hands of a good hacker.

Answer (score 2):

I'm impressed,  you are a leet hacker [Like me](http://milw0rm.com/author/677).   You need to move to web applications.  The majority of CVE numbers issued in the past few years have been in web applications.

Read these two papers:

http://www.securereality.com.au/studyinscarlet.txt

http://www.ngssoftware.com/papers/HackproofingMySQL.pdf

Get a LAMP stack and install these three applications:

http://sourceforge.net/projects/dvwa/  (php)

http://sourceforge.net/projects/gsblogger/ (php)

http://www.owasp.org/index.php/Category:OWASP_WebGoat_Project (j2ee)

You should download [w3af](http://w3af.sourceforge.net/) and master it.  Write plugins for it.  w3af is an awesome attack platform,  but it is buggy and has problems with DVWA,  it will rip up greyscale.   Acunetix is a good commercial scanner,  but it is expensive.

Answer (score 1):

I highly recommend "The Shellcoder's Handbook".  It's easily the best reference I've ever read when it comes to writing exploits.

If you're interested writing exploits, you're likely going to have to learn how to reverse engineer.  For 99% of the world, this means IDA Pro.  In my experience, there's no better IDA Pro book than Chris Eagle's "The IDA Pro Book".  He details pretty much everything you'll ever need to do in IDA Pro.

There's a pretty great reverse engineering community at OpenRCE.org.  Tons of papers and various helpful apps are available there.  I learned about this website at an excellent bi-annual reverse engineering conference called RECon. The next event will be in 2010.

Most research these days will be "low-hanging fruit".  The majority of talks at recent security conferences I've been to have been about vulnerabilities on mobile platforms (iPhone, Android, etc) where there are few to none of the protections available on modern OSes.

In general, there won't be a single reference out there that will explain how to write a modern exploit, because there's a whole host of protections built into OSes.  For example, say you've found a heap vulnerability, but that pesky new Safe Unlinking feature in Windows is keeping you from gaining execution.  You'd have to know that two geniuses researched this feature and [found a flaw](http://www.docstoc.com/docs/13476700/Reliable-Windows-Heap-Exploits).

Good luck in your studies.  Exploit writing is extremely frustrating, and EXTREMELY rewarding!

Bah!  The spam thingy is keeping me from posting all of my links.  Sorry!

Comment: You have never written an exploit.   You don't have to decompile code to exploit it. Blackbox fuzzing is very successful.   You do need a debugger to write an exploit.

Answer (score 1):

DEP (Data Execution Prevention), NX (No-Execute) and other security enhancements that specifically disallow execution are easily by-passed by using another exploit techniques such as Ret2Lib or Ret2Esp. When an application is compiled it usually is done so with other libraries (Linux) or DLLs (Windows). These Ret2* techniques simply call an existing function() that resides in memory.

For example, in a normal exploit you may overflow the stack and then take control of the return address (EIP) with the address of a NOP Sled, your Shellcode or an Environmental Variable that contains your shellcode. When attempting this exploit on a system that does not allow the stack to be executable your code will not run. Instead, when you overflow the return address (EIP) you can point it to an existing function within memory such as system() or execv(). You pre populate the required registers with the parameters this function expects and now you can call /bin/sh without having to execute anything from the stack.

For more information look here:

http://web.textfiles.com/hacking/smackthestack.txt